# Different between throwException in runtime and compile

Tags: java, exception, compilation, runtime

I just come across an interview question:
will java throwException at compile or runtime?
Basically I know java should throw exception at runtime since there is a type of exception
called runtime exception, but how about compile? I am still confused. Anyone can help me 
to explain these two a bit?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

A Java program will not throw an exception at compile time.  Thus, when people talk about "runtime exceptions", the word "runtime" is technically redundant.  However, they could well be including the redundant word "runtime" for a reason; for example

> "Please be clear.  Is the error in your program a compile time error or a runtime exception?"

Here, the speaker is trying to elicit a more precise description from someone who is being vague in their error reports.  (If you stay around StackOverflow for long enough, you will encounter many Q&As where it is necessary to ask questions like that to figure what the OP is actually asking.)

---

On the other hand, the Java exception hierarchy has an exception called `RuntimeException` (one word!) which is one of the two superclasses of checked exceptions.  So it is also possible that someone could use the phrase "runtime exception" to mean an *unchecked* exception.  (But I think that is poor terminology ...)